# Kali Linux and hotspot wifi host

Tags: internet, internet-connection, kali-linux

I'm running a Kali Linux Guest (VirtualBox) on a Windows 10 host. I have internet from an android device but on Kali Linux i don't have. Does anyone know how can i connect the guest to the internet ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to always use the internet connection of the host, no matter which it is connected to (Tethering, Wifi, Ethernet) you can just set the network connection of the guest to NAT.

It's also described within the official [documentation.](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_nat)

Comment: i've selected NAT and i still don't have internet :(

Comment: Reboot the guest or run `dhclient eth0`.